# On makemigrations Auto-generated field 'objectjourney_ptr' clashes with declared field of the same name

Tags: django, django-models, migration

#parent class

```
    class ObjectJourney(Base):        
        journey_type = models.ForeignKey('Journey.JourneyType')
        entry_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        exit_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

#child class

```
    class BookingJourney(ObjectJourney):
        journey_object = models.ForeignKey('RequestBooking.Booking')
        journey_entity = models.ForeignKey(
            'UserManagement.C24customer', related_name='journeys')
```

## Migrations file contains

```
    migrations.CreateModel(
                    name='BookingJourney',
                    fields=[
                        ('objectjourney_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='Journey.ObjectJourney')),
                    ],
                    options={
                        'abstract': False,
                    },
                    bases=('Journey.objectjourney',),
            ),
```

#Following are the error trails visible in terminal

```
    File "/home/jagdamba/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 308, in render_multiple
        model.render(self)
    File "/home/jagdamba/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 579, in render
        return type(self.name, bases, body)
    File "/home/jagdamba/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 253, in __new__
        base.__name__,
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Auto-generated field 'objectjourney_ptr' in class 'BookingJourney' for parent_link to base class 'ObjectJourney' clashes with declared field of the same name.
```

## My attempts to solve this error

```
    -Deleted migrations and created new migration.
    -ALso followed steps of this article...
    https://www.kidstrythisathome.com/2016/10/wtf-django-moving-models-part1.html
```

Comment: Can you try to delete this migration and run `./manage.py makemigrations` again? I think that this migration is not relevant for current `BookingJourney` model.

Comment: @TimofeyKatalnikov  did tried deleting and creating new migrations but it still won't work and raises the same error